# Select UI Element by filtering properties in coded ui

Tags: coded-ui-tests

I have a web application. And I am using coded ui to write automated tests to test the application.

I have a dropdown with a text box. Which on entering values in the textbox, the values in the dropdown gets filtered based on the text entered.

[image]

If I type inside textbox like 'Admin', I will get below options like this:

[image]

And I need to capture the two options displayed.

But using IE Developer tool (F12), I am not able to capture the filtered options, because the options that are displayed do not have any unique property (like this below). And the options that are NOT displayed have a class="hidden" property

Any way to capture the elements that are displayed by applying some kind of filter like 'Select ui elements whose class != hidden'

Thanks in advance!!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

HI please try below code will it works for you or not.By traversing all those controls that have class ="hidden"

```
WpfWindow mainWindow = new WpfWindow();
            mainWindow.SearchProperties.Add(HtmlControl.PropertyNames.ClassName, "hidden");
            UITestControlCollection collection = mainWindow.FindMatchingControls();
            foreach (UITestControl links in collection)
            {

                HtmlHyperlink mylink = (HtmlHyperlink)links;

                Console.WriteLine(mylink.InnerText);
            }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I wanted the controls without classname as "hidden".

Comment: ok then you have to add some dynamic id or you need to append some attribute at run time in drop down listing,so that you are able to determine the control..without that their is no way to catch that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there is a way to do it by search properties, but there are other approaches.

One way would be to brute force difference the collections.  Find all the list items, then find the hidden ones and do a difference.

```
HtmlControl listControl = /* find the UL somehow */

HtmlControl listItemsSearch = new HtmlControl(listControl);
listItemsSearch.SearchProperties.Add(HtmlControl.PropertyNames.TagName, "li");

HtmlControl hiddenListItemsSearch = new HtmlControl(listControl);
hiddenListItemsSearch.SearchProperties.Add(HtmlControl.PropertyNames.TagName, "li");
hiddenListItemsSearch.SearchProperties.Add(HtmlControl.PropertyNames.ClassName, "hidden");

var listItems = listItemsSearch.FindMatchingControls().Except(hiddenListItemsSearch.FindMatchingControls());
```

You will only be able to iterate this collection one time so if you need to iterate multiple times, create a function that returns this search.

```
var listItemsFunc = () => listItemsSearch.FindMatchingControls().Except(hiddenListItemsSearch.FindMatchingControls());

foreach(var listItem in listItemsFunc()){
 // iterate 1
}

foreach(var listItem in listItemsFunc()){
 // iterate 2
}
```

The other way I would consider doing it would be to filter based on the controls which have a clickable point and take up space on the screen (ie, not hidden).

```
listItemsSearch.FindMatchingControls().Where(x => {
    try { x.GetClickablePoint(); return x.Width > 0 && x.Height > 0; } catch { return false; }
});
```